# In OpenAPI, how to define an XML element with attributes AND content?

Tags: xml, swagger, openapi

I would like to describe the XML response payload of a RESTful interface with OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0). However, I struggle describing a particular XML tag in the OpenAPI data model.

I can't get Swagger UI to create an appropriate example XML tag in this form, with an attribute *and* content between the opening and closing XML tags:

```
<Person id="bar">foo</Person>
```

The documentation ([here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#xml-attribute-prefix-and-namespace)) only describes how to model a tag with sub tags (`type: object`) or a tag with content (`type: string`), but not both at the same time.

I tried this, which the Swagger Editor accepts without any errors or warnings:

```yaml
definitions:
  Person:
    type: string
    example: foo
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        example: bar
        xml:
          attribute: true
```

but it will be rendered by Swagger UI to the following example:

```
<Person id="bar"></Person>
```

As you can see, no "foo" content in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to represent that using the [OpenAPI Specification 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#openapi-specification), 3.0, or 3.1

This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630) and could be addressed in future versions of the specification.

Comment: I'm not sure if they updated the OpenApi Specification 2.0 since you've posted this answer, but if I understand the question correctly, it is actually possible.