# How to specify the default XML element text in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm building an OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0 definition for the following XML payload to use within the Swagger UI:

```xml
<addressElement>
    <key type="RECORD_ID" item="3">Enter value here</key>
</addressElement>
```

I'm having an issue figuring out how to display the default value 'Enter value here' for the element `key`. Where would one place this default value in an OpenAPI definition? My definition looks like this:

```json
    "definitions": {
     "addressElement": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Address Element",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
          "type":{
            "type": "string",
            "example": "RECORD_ID",
            "xml":{
              "attribute": true
            }
          },
          "item":{
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": "3",
            "xml":{
              "attribute": true
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
    "xml": {
      "name": "addressElement"
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger XML attribute and content definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023864/swagger-xml-attribute-and-content-definition)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible because OpenAPI does not have a way to represent XML elements with attributes such as

```xml
<key type="RECORD_ID" item="3">Enter value here</key>
```

Attributes can only be defined for objects

```xml
<obj attr="value">
  <elem>Some text</elem>
</obj>
```

but not for simple `<elem>text</elem>` elements.

There's an open issue about this limitation here:
[How to represent XML elements with attributes](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630)

That said, OpenAPI Specification maintainers are considering an option to use [alternative data modeling schemas](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1532) (such as XSD Schema), so your use case might be supported in a future version of OpenAPI.