# How do I describe schema object with value?

Tags: swagger, openapi

This is what I want

```
<messages>
        <message from="aaa" date="2019-07-09T13:41:12Z">sampletext1</message>
        <message from="bbb" date="2019-07-09T14:26:36Z">sampletext2</message>
</messages>
```

This is what I tried

```
messages:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    message:
      type: "array"
      xml:
        name: "message"
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/message"
  xml:
    name: "messages"      

message:
      type: "object"
      xml:
        name: "message"
      properties:
        from:
          type: "string"
        date:
          type: "string"
          format: "date-time"
        value:
          type: "string"
          example: "sample text"
```

But this represents the following.

```
<messages>
    <message>
        <from>string</from>
        <date>2019-07-09T19:47:47.264Z</date>
        <value>sample text</value>
    </message>
</messages>
```

How do I get the properties "from" and "date" in the "message" tag, and represent the sample text between the message tags as a value with no "value" tags with openapi 3.0.2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the default XML element text in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54164941/113116), [Swagger XML attribute and content definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023864/swagger-xml-attribute-and-content-definition)

Comment: This is currently not supported, as explained in the linked questions.

Comment: @Helen Thank you