# Issue describing an object for XML in Swagger 2.0 from C#

Tags: c#, xml, swagger, openapi

I am currently working on documenting an api that has some funky xml serialization "Tricks" going on.  Its a third party api that I want to wrap and also provide our clients with a swagger file that shows both XML and JSON (then the wrapper will always send XML to the third party API).

Issue one is is the following class:

```
public class DistanceValue
{
    /// <remarks />
    [XmlAttribute]
    public DistanceUOMType UOM { get; set; }

    /// <remarks />
    [XmlText]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

This gets represented as `<Distance UOM="Mi">305.0</Distance>` in the XMl.

Because I want to keep the changes to the input object to the wrapper minimal (mainly so I don't have to have our existing clients update their code to consume the new service) I am stuck trying to describe the xml side of the swagger.

I currently have this:

```
DistanceValue:
  type: object
  properties:
    uom:
      format: string
      xml:
        attribute: true
      enum:
        - MI
        - KM
      type: string
    value:
      format: double
      type: number
```

Which gets close as the below is coming out (the attribute)

```
<distance uom="MI">
  <value>0</value>
</distance>
```

The issue is that I cant see in the openapi 2.0 spec (again third party limitations) how to get the value of zero as the xml text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42023864/113116) [have a way](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SwaggerHub/Swagger-Definition-object-default-value/m-p/176972/highlight/true#M714) to define attributes for XML elements with text content such as

```xml
<Distance UOM="Mi">305.0</Distance>
```

You can only define attributes for XML elements that have child elements, i.e.:

```xml
<distance uom="MI">
  <value>0</value>
</distance>
```

Here's the corresponding enhancement request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630