# OpenAPI annotation for non-attribute (inline) text value

Tags: java, xml, jackson, swagger, openapi

Say I want to model this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<something>
    <entry value="foo">some text</entry>
    <entry value="bar">some other text</entry>
</something>
```

With this kind of modeling:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "something")
public class Something {

  @Schema(name = "entry")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "entry")
  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
}


public class Entry {

  @XmlAttribute
  String value;

  @JacksonXmlText
  String inlineTxt;
}
```

My usage of `@JacksonXmlText` is clearly insufficient because this is what Swagger generates for me when I press `Try it out`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<something>
    <entry value="string">
        <inlineTxt>string</inlineTxt>
    </entry>
</something>
```

However, when I receive objects formed in the way I want to model, Jackson does the work properly. (The getters and what-not are generated by Lombok with other annotations not shown here for the purpose of conciseness.)

**How do I get OpenAPI to generate an example object which doesn't have those `<inlineTxt>` tags?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42023864/113116) XML elements with both attributes and text such as

```xml
<entry value="foo">some text</entry>
```

This means your XML structure cannot be represented using OpenAPI and the related Java annotations.

Comment: Considering I cannot change the input data, how can I adapt ?

Answer (score 0):

For my project work this example:

```
ttlIntrBkSttlmAmt:
      type: string
      xml:
        name: TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#AmountMoreZero'
```

in pom.xml add import:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.1.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            ...
            <importMappings>
                <importMapping>AmountMoreZero=com.example.iso20022.http.v1.schema.AmountMoreZero</importMapping>
            </importMappings>
            ...
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

And create this file in namespase com.example.iso20022.http.v1.schema.AmountMoreZero:

```
public class AmountMoreZero  implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("ccy")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Ccy")
    private String ccy;

    @JacksonXmlText
    BigDecimal value;
}
```