# OpenAPI 3.0 - Issue describing an object for XML tag in OpenAPI 3.0 (Swagger 3.0) objects that have both attributes and a value

Tags: xml, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I can't get Swagger UI to create an appropriate XML tag with an attribute and content ( objects that have both attributes and a value ) :

```
<filter id="id001" attr1="admin">Administrator</filter>
```

and instead, I get this

```
<filter>Administrator</filter>
```

if I use this schema

```
components:
  schemas:
    Filter:
      type: object
      example: Administrator
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          example: id001
          xml:
            attribute: true
        attr1:
          type: string
          example: admin
          xml:
            attribute: true
```

or this

```
<filter attr1="id001" attr1="admin"></filter>
```

if I use this schema

```
components:
  schemas:
    Filter:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          example: id001
          xml:
            attribute: true
        attr1:
          type: string
          example: admin
          xml:
            attribute: true
```

I try many ways to solve this issue but no luck

[image: here if I add the example]

[image: here if I without the example]

Comment: To give more details to your question, add the screenshot of the swagger UI output.

Comment: I add the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065906/8607180) this scenario currently [doesn't seem to be supported](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630) by the OpenAPI spec. But you can still achieve this result by:

- [using a nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984905/8607180) with `type: object` (seems hacky to me)
- manually crafting examples for your API spec (see below)

Here is how you can specify an example under the `content` section:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Sample API
  description: A sample API to illustrate OpenAPI concepts

paths:
  /filters:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: filters
          content:
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Filters"
              example: |
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <filters>
                  <filter id="id001" attr1="admin">Administrator</filter>
                </filters>
```

Or, if you want to reuse examples, you can place them under `components` and reference them in the `examples` section of a method:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Sample API
  description: A sample API to illustrate OpenAPI concepts

paths:
  /filters:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: filters
          content:
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Filters"
              examples:
                Filters:
                  $ref: "#/components/examples/Filters"

components:
  schemas:
  # ...

  examples:
    Filters:
      value: |
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <filters>
          <filter id="id001" attr1="admin">Administrator</filter>
        </filters>
```